# PHP Imagick cannot set image background color

Tags: php, background-color, imagick

I load transparent png image and i every time i try to set bg color using `setimagebackgroundcolor()` it still transparent

```
    $input_img = new Imagick();

    $input_img->setBackgroundColor("#ff0000");

    $input_img->readImage("transparent.png");

    $input_img->setimagebackgroundcolor("#00ff00");

    $input_img->setImageFormat("png");

    $input_img->setimagebackgroundcolor("#ff00ff");

    $input_img->writeimage("image.png");
```

Comment: Seeing this problem as well. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: You confuse color and opacity. If a pixel is transparent, it can have any color and is still transparent. You have to change transparency first. Or set the color with transparency.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is using: `$im = $im->flattenImages();`:

```php
<?php
$im = new Imagick($filename);

$im->setImageBackgroundColor('#ffffff');
$im = $im->flattenImages();

$im->setImageFormat("jpeg");
$im->setImageCompressionQuality(95);
$im->writeImage($filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first line sets a new `Imagickpixel` object for the color; the second line creates a 1920x1200 image using that as image color.

```php
$color = new ImagickPixel("white");
$input_img->newImage(1920,1200, $color);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this!

```
$imput_img->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('blue'));
```