# How to change html body color created by php header content image?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I have created an in image using PHP. I want to change the body background color created by php imagick. For more clarification, I have added code and output image.

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$image = new Imagick('d.png');
$image->setImageFormat("png");

echo $image;
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Imagick - Make black background white](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970421/imagick-make-black-background-white)

Comment: no....i have tried these also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be easily solved using two seperate file html and php.

page.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <img src="image.php" alt="" />
</body>
</html>
```

image.php

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: image/png');
$im = new Imagick('image.png');

$im->setImageFormat("png");

echo $im;

?>
```